# How to get projects that I have permission to start in processmaker?

Tags: rest, projects, processmaker

http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/REST_API_Designer#get_projects

---

this api return all projects in my workflow including that I have not involved in.  Any way to get projects that I can start?

Answer (score 0):

I was told  "/api/1.0/workflow/light/start-case" would get the projects I involved, while "/projects" get all projects.

Comment: The api is not supported publicly, may will not available later.

Comment: Despite the fact that is not publicly documented, is the one used by processmaker mobile app, so it should be mantained for a while. At least for all pm 3.x versions,

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to execute these steps, for example in Postman:

For Desktop

```
GET: {{url}}/{{workspace}}/oauth2/token
```

url: Your Site
workspace: Your Workspace

```
**Headers**
Authorization: Basic eC1wbS1sb2NhbC1jbGllbnQ6MTc5YWQ0NWM2Y2UyY2I5N2NmMTAyOWUyMTIwNDZlODE=
Content-Type: application/json

{
"grant_type":"password", 
"username":"admin", 
"password":"admin"}
```

Now that we already have the access_token we need to try it out in the next endpoints

```
GET: {{url}}/api/1.0/{{workspace}}/light/start-case

url: Your Site
workspace: Your Workspace

**Headers:**
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
```